# Spring MVC <form:xxx> tags

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc

I have a doubt that in our web applications generally we are using spring MVC and  for view purpose Spring MVC tags, So while writing Spring MVC tags we are using `<form:xxx>` tags like `<form:input>` `<form:option>` `<form:select>` also `<form:label>` like this. My confusion is that generally in HTML we are using all these above tags without including `<form:xxx>` so what is the exact difference in between both the tags and why `<form:xxx>` tag is needed when it comes to Spring MVC. Is there any object associates to it or what?

Comment: In your initial question you mixed up "3rd party JSP tags" with JSTL. That's not correct. To learn what exactly JSTL is, head to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: @BalusC Yeah I was a little bit wrong about my concept but right now i got this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind the user values collected using form to Object, Then you will need to use Spring form tag. For example..

```
<form:form action="actionUrl" method="post" modelAttribute="loginForm">
    <form:input path="empId" placeholder="Enter Employee Id"/>
    <form:errors path="empId" cssClass="error"/>
    <form:password path="password" placeholder="********"/>
    <form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form:form>
```

Here `modelAttribute="loginForm"` , loginForm is a Object of Java Class with two fields `empId` and `password`.

```
public class LoginForm{
    private Integer empId;
    private String password;

    //getters and setters
}
```

So, Now when you submit the Login form, the values are automatically bound to java object which you can access in your controller method. Like

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/login"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String authLogin(@Valid LoginForm loginForm,BindingResult result,ModelMap model){
      //Your code logic
   }
```

So, spring form binds form values automatically to java object and saves from accessing each request parameter manually. These values can also be validated using validation framework.